# Почему View = null

Tags: android

Разбираюсь с программированием для Андроид.
Не могу понять одну вещь:

```
public class ImFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = getView();
    if (view != null) 
        ImageView imImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.im_image);
    /* ....... */
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_im, container, false);
}
```

Почему view == null.

Почему условие не срабатывает...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

потом что View все еще null.
ваще "раздутие" view происходит только после того, как вы укажите разметку. а вы это делаете в return
а вот в методе `onViewCreated` - `view` уже будет существовать.
изучайте ЖЦ фрагмента
https://russianblogs.com/images/787/9da2ec547022495f920c8bc603971603.png